# Does every nontrivial quotient $\mathcal{H}/\Gamma$ have an unramified cover

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

If $\Gamma$ is a proper finite index subgroup of $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \cong C_2*C_3$, then must there exist a $\Gamma'$ finite index in $\Gamma$ such that $\mathcal{H}/\Gamma'\rightarrow\mathcal{H}/\Gamma$ is unramified?

This is clear enough if $\Gamma$ is torsion-free, since then the fundamental group of $\mathcal{H}/\Gamma$ is just $\Gamma$. If $\Gamma$ has torsion, the situation seems less clear.

What if we assume $\mathcal{H}/\Gamma$ to have genus $> 0$?